# Add transcript field to sonata media bundle youtube provider

Tags: youtube, provider, sonata-media-bundle

I would like to extend the youtube provider in order to add a text field to add the transcript of the video.
I'm using Symfony 3.4 and the latest version of sonata media bundle.
Can anyone tell me how to do it?

Cheers